# how to stub request.get three times? with 2 same url and 1 different url?

Tags: request, sinon, node-request, sinon-chai

I need to write unit testcase for following piece of code. Here urls are external api calls, so I need to mock these. For rest of the testcases I have used sinon. So would like to write these in **sinon only**.

```
function 1 {
  async.waterfall() {
    function 2();
    function 3();
  }
}

function 2(callback) {
    url2_1 = "/calculatorFunctionList"
    request.get(url2_1,function (err, res, body) {
        return callback("with some diff response")
    })}

function 3(callback) {
    url3_1 = "addition/values="+somevalue1
    url3_2 = "addition/values="+somevalue2
    request.get(url3_1,function (err, res, body) {
        if(!err) {
            request.get(url3_2, function (err, res, body) {
                return callback("with some response")
            })
        }
    })
}
```

I need to stub these requests. How can I do this? Also how and when to call restore for stub so that it won't mess up with other request stub? Currently both stubs are not getting mocked.

Answer (score 0):

Sinon - at its core (forget `lolex` and `nise` for a moment) - explicitly deals with stubbing and spying on javascript functions. That's it. It does not concern itself with module loaders or Node *per se*.

So it does not know how to hook into Node's module loader (`require`) and stub out dependencies by itself. For the general case, you have two options:

1. Supply your module (the System-Under-Test) with injection points (say, a `function setRequestModule(module){ request = module }`, which could be used to supply a Sinon stub.
2. Use a link-level to intercept calls to the module system to load dependencies and swap them out. See [this article on Sinon's how-to section](https://sinonjs.org/how-to/link-seams-commonjs/) for how to do this.

That was the general case, but since you are dealing with network level stubbing, there is a third option, which is related to the second one, which involves hooking into the http layer in Node and setting up fake requests and responses there using `nock`.

This would look like this:

```
const nock = require('nock')

const scope = nock('https://api.github.com')
  .get('/repos/atom/atom/license')
  .reply(200, {
    license: {
      key: 'mit',
      name: 'MIT License',
      spdx_id: 'MIT',
      url: 'https://api.github.com/licenses/mit',
      node_id: 'MDc6TGljZW5zZTEz',
    },
  })
```

This is what I would normally do, but since you insist on only using Sinon you are left with the first option.

**Elaboration of the first option: inject dependencies**

Your functions `2` and `3` (invalid javascript identifiers, btw) are both dependant on the module `request` and its method `get` to have their results. To be able to control what is returned by `request.get` you would then need to supply your module with a *different* version of `request` for your tests. This can be done using dependency injection.

To start with, I assume your function starts with an import of the `request` module, meaning the first few lines includes a statement looking like this:

```
const request = require('request');
```

You would need to change this statement so that the `request` constant can be replaced, meaning it would now look like this:

```
let request = require('request');
```

To be able to control your dependency you can now add a new function to your exports:

```
module.exports.setRequestModule = function (stub){
    request = stub;
}
```

To use this in your tests you would then need to do this in your tests:

```
const myModule = require('../src/my-module');
const myRequestStub = {};

myModule.setRequestModule(myRequestStub);

it('should return the expected response', () => {
    const expectedOutput = "with some response";
    myRequestStub.get = function (url, callback) {
         callback(null, expectedOutput);
    }

    myModule.doSomething() ...
    // do test
});
```

**Alternatively**
You could also *expose* the request object in your module:

```
module.exports._request = request;
```

You could then, for instance, use `sinon` to instrument it by stubbing the `get` method from your tests.

```
const myModule = require('../src/my-module');

sinon.stub(myModule._request, 'get').callsFake( (url, cb) => cb("hello!") );
```

Comment: so how to do it with first option? Could you elaborate more? or could give example?

Comment: I thought it was sufficiently clear from the text, but I can add a new section. Give me 10 mins.